# How to response from servlet to client?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm trying to do a simple static login with google app engine and android app like this:

Server:

```
public class StreetMeetSignServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)     throws  IOException 
    {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String userName,password;   
        userName = request.getParameter("username");
        password = request.getParameter("password");
        if(userName.equalsIgnoreCase("A") && password.equals("B"))
        {
            out.print("yes");
        }
        else
        {
            out.print("no");
        }       
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://myserver.appspot.com/", postParameters);

    String res=response.toString();
    System.out.println("res is: "  + res);
    res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");

    if(res.equals("yes"))
        error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
    else
        error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");
```

But in the res string i have the all html code genreated on my jsp..
Why is that?
There is a tutorial from A to Z that show how to connect android app to google app engine servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `executeHttpPost` method you should pass the full path to your servlet, e.g.

```
    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://myserver.appspot.com/path/to/servlet", postParameters);
```

Did you register your servlet in `web.xml`? What is the path?

Comment: how do i fill this full path?  

  i tried
  response =     CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://myserver.appspot.com/server.jsp", postParameters);  
and it did'nt work

Comment: O.k now I got it. I should have used the mapping path.. Thanks